# How to install/configure mod_mono on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, ubuntu, mono

On Ubuntu 14.04.3 I'm running the latest version of the Mono Framework and MonoDevelop, see

[How to install the latest version of Mono and MonoDevelop on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006849/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-mono-and-monodevelop-on-ubuntu)

My goal is to get ASP.net MVC 5.2 website running under apache. So I installed mono apache server4

```
sudo apt-get install mono-apache-server4
```

..but the installation of mod_mono failed

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-mono : Depends: mono-apache-server (< 3.8.1) but 4.2-2~xamarin1 is to be installed or
                                mono-apache-server4 (< 3.8.1) but 4.2-2~xamarin1 is to be installed or
                                mono-apache-server2 (< 3.8.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I googled a lot on this problem, but I cannot solve the issue. Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this was a bug I introduced a few days ago with an XSP package update - the mod-mono package is hardcoded to refuse to install against unexpectedly new XSP, but I had forgotten about it.

Packages built & uploaded for all architectures.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm it's working now. I executed the following commands: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a 3rd party repository, delete it.

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

After that,`apt-get update`.

**Try it again!**

Comment: This solves not the issue. Thank you for sharing your idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions on the original page: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives

There is a section "mod_mono (Ubuntu 13.10 and later, Debian 8.0 and later)", and it says:

> To enable mod_mono installation on Ubuntu 13.10 and later, and Debian 8.0 and later (and their derivatives), you will need to add a second repository to your system, in addition to the generic Debian/Ubuntu repository above (if you don’t use sudo, be sure to switch to root):
>
> echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-apache24-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

Comment: I tried that already, but that does not solve the issue. The same error occurs again (as in my first post).

Comment: I can reproduce your problem on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

It seems the package libapache2-mod-mono has not been updated for 4.2: http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/pool/main/m/mod-mono/

directhex is working on the packages now

Comment: Ah that's so cool. Hope there will be a solution soon. Thanks :-)